# What is the Vedic concept of universe creation?

Tags: vedas, universe

I read big bang theory of universe creation, but I want to know the Vedic concept of universe creation and in how much time it is created?

Comment: Please read the question before marking duplicate. Your suggested question is explaining big bang theory. I want to know about vedic concepts.

Comment: Please read all answers. That question is for all the questions which ask for reason for creation. Vedas is also covered in it. Nasadiya Sukta is a part of Rigveda.

Comment: Big Bang & Vedic cosmogony (and others) do not disagree in content, only in metaphor. Physics uses mathematical symbolism which can be widely understood today. Vedas use symbols which could be widely understood by South Asians 3,500 years ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this answer I will not be quoting the exact verses initially, however I will be providing the links wherein you can read.

The Vedic concept of creation includes the "HOW" and the "WHY" of the entire cosmic manifestation.

**What was there before creation?**

Supreme personality of godhead, Lord Krishna who is beyond material creation exists before creation and after annihilation. Period after annihilation and before creation all living entities are dormant in the form of the Lord. [SB [3.5.23]](https://www.vedabase.com/sb/3/5/23)

**Reason for creation**

The compassion of the Lord towards living entities: Lord is mercifully putting so much endeavour from His side to reclaim conditioned beings, creating universe, residing as supersoul in heart to guide and sanction jiva’s desires, maintaining and winding the universe, sending acharyas to reclaim fallen souls and so on. [SB [3.5.3]](https://www.vedabase.com/sb/3/5/3)

The Lord felt incomplete without His plenary expansions and unsatisfied, so he desired to create the manifestation. The material potency was dormant. [SB [3.5.24]](https://www.vedabase.com/sb/3/5/24)

CREATION IN BRIEF (From Srimad Bhagavatam)

> SB 2.10.3 
>  
>   
>   **bhuta-matrendriya-dhiyam 
>  janma sarga udahrtah
>
>   brahmano guna-vaisamyad
>  visargah paurusah smrtah**
>  
>  The
>   elementary creation of sixteen items of matter—namely the five
>   elements [fire, water, land, air and sky], sound, form, taste, smell,
>   touch, and the eyes, ears, nose, tongue, skin and mind—is known as
>   sarga, whereas subsequent resultant interaction of the modes of
>   material nature is called visarga.
>
> SB 2.10.6
>   
>   **nirodho ’syanusayanam
>  atmanah saha saktibhih
>  muktir
>   hitvanyatha rupam
>  sva-rupena vyavasthitih**
>  
>  The merging of
>   the living entity, along with his conditional living tendency, with
>   the mystic lying down of the Maha-Visnu is called the winding up of
>   the cosmic manifestation. Liberation is the permanent situation of the
>   form of the living entity after he gives up the changeable gross and
>   subtle material bodies.
>
> SB 2.10.10
>
> **puruso ’ndam vinirbhidya
>  yadasau sa vinirgatah
>  atmano ’yanam
>   anvicchann
>  apo ’sraksic chucih sucih**
>
> After separating the different universes, the gigantic universal form
>   of the Lord [Maha-Visnu], which came out of the causal ocean, the
>   place of appearance for the first purusa-avatara, entered into each of
>   the separate universes, desiring to lie on the created transcendental
>   water [Garbhodaka].
>
> SB 2.10.15
>
> **antah sarira akasat
>  purusasya vicestatah
>  ojah saho balam
>   jajne
>  tatah prano mahan asuh**
>
> From the sky situated within the transcendental body of the
>   manifesting Maha-Visnu, sense energy, mental force and bodily strength
>   are all generated, as well as the sum total of the fountainhead of the
>   total living force.
>
> SB 2.10.17
>
> **pranenaksipata ksut trd
>  antara jayate vibhoh
>  pipasato jaksatas
>   ca
>  pran mukham nirabhidyata**
>
> The living force, being agitated by the virat-purusa, generated hunger
>   and thirst, and when He desired to drink and eat, the mouth
>   opened.
>
> SB 2.10.18
>
> **mukhatas talu nirbhinnam
>  jihva tatropajayate
>  tato nana-raso
>   jajne
>  jihvaya yo ’dhigamyate**
>
> From the mouth the palate became manifested, and thereupon the tongue
>   was also generated. After this all the different tastes came into
>   existence so that the tongue can relish them.
>
> SB 2.10.19
>
> **vivaksor mukhato bhumno
>  vahnir vag vyahrtam tayoh
>  jale
>   caitasya suciram
>  nirodhah samajayata**
>
> When the Supreme desired to speak, speeches were vibrated from the
>   mouth. Then the controlling deity Fire was generated from the mouth.
>   But when He was lying in the water, all these functions remained
>   suspended.
>
> SB 2.10.20
>
> **nasike nirabhidyetam
>  dodhuyati nabhasvati
>  tatra vayur
>   gandha-vaho
>  ghrano nasi jighrksatah**
>
> Thereafter, when the supreme purusa desired to smell odors, the
>   nostrils and respiration were generated, the nasal instrument and
>   odors came into existence, and the controlling deity of air, carrying
>   smell, also became manifested.
>
> SB 2.10.21
>
> **yadatmani niralokam
>  atmanam ca didrksatah
>  nirbhinne hy aksini
>   tasya
>  jyotis caksur guna-grahah**
>
> Thus when everything existed in darkness, the Lord desired to see
>   Himself and all that was created. Then the eyes, the illuminating god
>   Sun, the power of vision and the object of sight all became
>   manifested.
>
> SB 2.10.23
>
> **vastuno mrdu-kathinya-
>  laghu-gurv-osna-sitatam
>  jighrksatas
>   tvan nirbhinna
>  tasyam roma-mahi-ruhah
>  tatra cantar bahir
>   vatas
>  tvaca labdha-guno vrtah**
>
> When there was a desire to perceive the physical characteristics of
>   matter, such as softness, hardness, warmth, cold, lightness and
>   heaviness, the background of sensation, the skin, the skin pores, the
>   hairs on the body and their controlling deities (the trees) were
>   generated. Within and outside the skin is a covering of air through
>   which sense perception became prominent.
>
> SB 2.10.25
>
> **gatim jigisatah padau
>  ruruhate ’bhikamikam
>  padbhyam yajnah
>   svayam havyam
>  karmabhih kriyate nrbhih**
>
> Thereupon, because of His desiring to control movement, His legs
>   became manifested, and from the legs the controlling deity named Visnu
>   was generated. By His personal supervision of this act, all varieties
>   of human being are busily engaged in dutiful occupational
>   sacrifice.
>
> SB 2.10.26
>
> **nirabhidyata sisno vai
>  prajanandamrtarthinah
>  upastha asit
>   kamanam
>  priyam tad-ubhayasrayam**
>
> Thereupon, for sexual pleasure, begetting offspring and tasting
>   heavenly nectar, the Lord developed the genitals, and thus there is
>   the genital organ and its controlling deity, the Prajapati. The object
>   of sexual pleasure and the controlling deity are under the control of
>   the genitals of the Lord.
>
> SB 2.10.27
>
> **utsisrksor dhatu-malam
>  nirabhidyata vai gudam
>  tatah payus tato
>   mitra
>  utsarga ubhayasrayah**
>
> Thereafter, when He desired to evacuate the refuse of eatables, the
>   evacuating hole, anus, and the sensory organ thereof developed along
>   with the controlling deity Mitra. The sensory organ and the evacuating
>   substance are both under the shelter of the controlling deity.
>
> SB 2.10.28
>
> **asisrpsoh purah purya
>  nabhi-dvaram apanatah
>  tatrapanas tato
>   mrtyuh
>  prthaktvam ubhayasrayam**
>
> Thereafter, when He desired to move from one body to another, the
>   navel and the air of departure and death were combinedly created. The
>   navel is the shelter for both, namely death and the separating
>   force.
>
> SB 2.10.29
>
> **aditsor anna-pananamasan
>  kuksy-antra-nadayah
>  nadyah samudras
>   ca tayos
>  tustih pustis tad-asraye**
>
> When there was a desire to have food and drink, the abdomen and the
>   intestines and also the arteries became manifested. The rivers and
>   seas are the source of their sustenance and metabolism.
>
> SB 2.10.30
>
> **nididhyasor atma-mayam
>  hrdayam nirabhidyata
>  tato manas candra
>   iti
>  sankalpah kama eva ca**
>
> When there was a desire to think about the activities of His own
>   energy, then the heart (the seat of the mind), the mind, the moon,
>   determination and all desire became manifested.
>
> SB 2.10.31
>
> **tvak-carma-mamsa-rudhira-
>  medo-majjasthi-dhatavah
>
>   bhumy-ap-tejomayah sapta
>  prano vyomambu-vayubhih**
>
> The seven elements of the body, namely the thin layer on the skin, the
>   skin itself, the flesh, blood, fat, marrow and bone, are all made of
>   earth, water and fire, whereas the life breath is produced by the sky,
>   water and air.
>
> SB 2.10.32
>
> **gunatmakanindriyani
>  bhutadi-prabhava gunah
>  manah
>   sarva-vikaratma
>  buddhir vijnana-rupini**
>
> The sense organs are attached to the modes of material nature, and the
>   modes of material nature are products of the false ego. The mind is
>   subjected to all kinds of material experiences (happiness and
>   distress), and the intelligence is the feature of the mind’s
>   deliberation.
>
> SB 2.10.33
>
> **etad bhagavato rupam
>  sthulam te vyahrtam maya
>  mahy-adibhis
>   cavaranair
>  astabhir bahir avrtam**
>
> Thus by all this, the external feature of the Personality of Godhead
>   is covered by gross forms such as those of planets, which were
>   explained to you by me.
>
> SB 2.10.34
>
> **atah param suksmatamam
>  avyaktam nirvisesanam
>
>   anadi-madhya-nidhanam
>  nityam van-manasah param**
>
> Therefore beyond this [gross manifestation] is a transcendental
>   manifestation finer than the finest form. It has no beginning, no
>   intermediate stage and no end; therefore it is beyond the limits of
>   expression or mental speculation and is distinct from the material
>   conception.
>
> SB 2.10.41
>
> **sattvam rajas tama iti
>  tisrah sura-nr-narakah
>  tatrapy ekaikaso
>   rajan
>  bhidyante gatayas tridha
>  
>  yadaikaikataro
>   ’nyabhyam
>  sva-bhava upahanyate**
>
> According to the different modes of material nature—the mode of
>   goodness, the mode of passion and the mode of darkness—there are
>   different living creatures, who are known as demigods, human beings
>   and hellish living entities. O King, even a particular mode of nature,
>   being mixed with the other two, is divided into three, and thus each
>   kind of living creature is influenced by the other modes and acquires
>   its habits also.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you can post this answer to the original, then it would be appreciated. This question is closed as duplicate after you have started to answer the question. Posting to an open question will get more appreciation. Also, this question specifically asks for Veda references which are also covered in that question. So, it is good if you post there.

Comment: the question about vedas and this is only Puranic quotes...

Comment: I've mentioned it in the answer to the original question.